# Why I can't assign input value to react hook?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get input value and assign it to react hook.

`const { specName, setSpecName } = useState("");`

```
<input
          name="name"
          onChange={e => { setSpecName(e.target.value) }}
          value={specName}
          className="specialist-profile-input"
          type="text"
          placeholder={user.name} />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

When, I'm starting writing, pops up error "TypeError: setSpecName is not a function". I took a pattern from one guy and it's not working. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You have a **typo**: `const [ specName, setSpecName ] = useState("");`, see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Answer (score 2):

Because the return value of `useState` cannot be destructured as an object.

`const [specName, setSpecName] = useState("");`